# Can't access a UIButton when it's created dynamically in UITable view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I've created a `UIButton` dynamically in the table view cell. but there is a problem,- I'm not able to access the button or it's sender method.

When I click on a button it's giving the wrong tag or sometime it's not clickable. I've created button a with the help of for() loop in the tableview cell. I think the main problem is that I create the button in the for() loop. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIView   *viewDisplaySize;
        if (cell == nil)
        {
             NSString *myString =@"1111111:2222222:333333:44444:55555:6666:777777:888888888888:9999999999" ;


            NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
     for (int i=0; i < [myWords count]; i++) {

    //Create a button but can't able to get a correct tag 

    /// Or some time it's not click able
     }
```

Whole code--- [link of full code](http://pastie.org/9346875#10)

Comment: Where r u adding the button?

Comment: set tag like button.tag=indexPath.row

Comment: You mention that you're pretty sure the problem is that you create your button in the loop, but then you're not showing _how_ you're creating that button in the loop. Show how the button is created.

Comment: Please you all see my Whole code--- link of full code

Comment: Please see this http://pastie.org/9346875#10

Comment: Please see this pastie.org/9346875#10 @Stonz2

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that the way you're adding your subviews is not the best way. By adding the subviews inside a if(cell == nil) clause, and setting the tag value there, the tag value will never change. When the cell is reused, the tag will still be based on the row where it was created, not on where that reused cell now appears.

A better way to create your cell, would be to add any subviews you need in the init method of a custom cell class. This cleans up the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath so it only contains code you need to populate the cells. If the cell is made completely in code (no xib or storyboard for its view), then you should register the class (usually done in viewDidLoad of the table view controller) with registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:. Then, in cellForRowAtIndexPath there will be no need to check whether the cell is nil because it never will be. You still want to set the button's action and tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but now it will be reset for the proper row when the cell is reused.